# Communicator.exe takes 96% CPU

Tags: windows, cpu, communicator

My Communicator.exe is taking up 96% CPU.  I have to run this program for work to chat with my coworkers... what could be causing it to use such a high CPU percent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try a repair.  If that doesn't work try to do a re-install.  Hopefully that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.file.net/process/communicator.exe.html)

Communicator.exe is located in a subfolder of "C:\Program Files". The file size on Windows XP is 4,167,376 bytes.
There is an icon for this program on the taskbar next to the clock. The program has a visible window. The application can be uninstalled in the Control Panel. It is digitally signed. Program starts when Windows starts

see Registry key: HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run).

It is not a Windows core file. The application listens for or sends data on open ports to LAN or Internet. Communicator.exe is able to record inputs. Therefore the technical security rating is 6% dangerous, however also read the users reviews.

***Important: Some malware camouflage themselves as Communicator.exe, particularly if they are located in c:\windows or c:\windows\system32 folder***

Check it those one is good one or bad

Answer (score 0):

I find that it's usually not Communicator.exe which is primarily responsible, it's some collusion it has with Outlook.  I experienced the same problem you had, but due to continuing troubles with Outlook, I finally abandoned it and switched primarily over to OWA Outlook Web Access.  Amazingly around the same time, Communicator also got better.