# Run Microsoft Office Communicator in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode, office-communicator-2007, ms-office-communicator

The laptop I have is very slow if run in normal mode (Startup ~= 10 min) so I have started using it in safe mode.

It is considerably faster now but there's one problem: I need to use Microsoft Office Communicator, but it seems it is not able to run in safe mode.

I saw [some hacks to enable certain services](https://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=safe%20mode%20uninstall) but I can't seem to find the service name of `communicator`. Is some other hack required?

Comment: Have you tried to fix what is causing Windows to run slowly in "normal mode"? Hacking services, if done wrong, could do more damage than good.

Comment: Just reinstall the operating system. Running in safe mode isn't a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not a PC, its a laptop provided by my organisation. I just have to use it for 2 months. Till then, safe mode would do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicator.exe takes 96% CPU](http://superuser.com/questions/57392/communicator-exe-takes-96-cpu)